# Find the eigenvalues for 3 equations after variable separation

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues, education

I have to find the eigenvalues for three functions obtained with variable separation method.
The functions result from the following expression:

[image]
[image]

I tried with the following code:

```
W = 1.2;
Subscript[L, 1] = 0.5;
Subscript[L, 2] = 5;
Subscript[k, CLS] = 1.4;
Subscript[k, soil] = 2.2;
h = 2.5;
```

For Y:

```
eqy = Y''[y] + \[Beta]^2*Y[y] == 0;
icy1 = Y'[y] == 0 /. y -> 0;
icy2 = Y'[y] == 0 /. y -> W;
soly = DSolve[{eqy, icy1, icy2}, Y[y], {y, 0, W}]
eigfuns = Table[Y[y] /. sol[[1]] //. {\[FormalN] -> i, \[Beta] -> 5.235987755982989` \[FormalN]} /. {C[1] -> 1}, {i, 2}]
```

I don't understand why the result for Beta is double the solution I should obtain.
As for X:

```
eqx1 = Subscript[X, 1]''[x] + Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]^2*Subscript[X, 1][x] == 0;
eqx2 = Subscript[X, 2]''[x] + Subscript[\[Gamma], 2]^2*Subscript[X, 2][x] == 0;
icx1 = -Subscript[k, CLS]*Subscript[X, 1]'[x] + h*Subscript[X, 1][x] == 0 /. x -> 0;
icx2 = Subscript[X, 2][x] == 0 /. x -> Subscript[L, 2];
ccx1 = Subscript[X, 1][x] == Subscript[X, 2][x] /. x -> Subscript[L, 1];
ccx2 = Subscript[k, CLS]*Subscript[X, 1]'[x] == Subscript[k, soil]*Subscript[X, 2]'[x] /. x -> Subscript[L, 1];
solx = DSolve[{eqx1, eqx2, icx1, icx2, ccx1, ccx2}, Subscript[X, 1][x], Subscript[X, 2][x], {x, 0, Subscript[L, 2]}]
```

In this case, it says that "DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in Subscript[X, 1][x] should literally match the independent variables.".
Finally for Gamma:

```
eqt = \[CapitalGamma]'[t] + \[Lambda]^2*\[CapitalGamma][t] == 0;
ict1 = \[CapitalGamma][t] == 25 /. t -> 0;
solt = DSolve[{eqt, ict1}, \[CapitalGamma][t], {t, 0, 1000}]
```

I don't think I have enough conditions to find lambda.
Can you check if I used to proper BC and give me some suggestions to solve the problems?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have syntax errors: `sol[[1]]` should read: `soly[[1]]` . `Subscript[X, 1][x], Subscript[X, 2][x]` should read: `{Subscript[X, 1][x], Subscript[X, 2][x]}`   With this you get:  \[CapitalGamma][t] -> 25 E^(-t \[Lambda]^2)`

Comment: You mean {Subscript[X, 1][x], Subscript[X, 2][x]} in DSolve? Now it gives me 0 as the result for both the X functions. As for Gamma I already got that result, but I don't know what are the BC to find lambda.

Comment: Please correct the errors I indicated. Yes, I also get zero. But I can not see any lambda. The boundary condition should be obtained from your problem.

Comment: I corrected them. However, I know for sure that the result is not zero, but eqs. (34)-(35). Lambda is the eigenvalue for Gamma.